# XCode does not add c++ source files that are in subdirectories into Compile Sources

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode5

I use XCode 5.1 for C++ development. I have existing code which I add to the project by dragging files from Finder. The project shows all necessary `.h` and `.cpp` files. But when I click `Build Phases->Compile Sources`, I only see sources that from the root directory in my source structure. None of the source files from subdirectories appear in the Compile Sources. Why? And how to fix this?

Also, when I try to add the missing `.cpp` file from `Build Phases->Compile Sources` by pressing `+`, XCode does not expand the subdirectories, so I cannot select the missing `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is unbelievable. The only problem was that I was adding folder structure with `Create folder references for any added folders` option instead of `Create groups for any added folders`.

But still don't understand what is the difference in terms of recognition of source files.

Other peculiarity is that you should add resource files in opposite way (`Create folder references for any added folders`). Otherwise the iOS application does not find the files and does not compile.

Comment: I agree, it *is* unbelievable. Had I not found this answer, another day or more would have been wasted on this silly task.

Comment: I also run into the same thing earlier, and even though I saw the post, I didn't see where to select the Create groups initially until I resolve it later on.  Leaving this comment for others.  In Project navigator, right-click my project, select "Add files to <my_project>", click the Option button in the pop-up dialog, and select Create groups instead of Add folder references.  Any cpp files within the folder that you just added will now compile.

Comment: This is such a ridiculous problem. Thanks @frank and Narek

Comment: 8 years later, running XCode 15 and this is still a thing. My problem comes after I add the files as groups, they show in Compile Sources and Project Headers, but I keep getting a "MyHeader.hpp File not found" error on build (even though I can command-click in the editor to the header. Thoughts?