# Recursively add cpp files in folder to Compile Sources

Tags: xcode

According to this [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_an_Existing_File_or_Folder.html):

> Select the destination targets for your selected files or folder
>   references. New folder references and files that can participate in
>   the build process become members of the selected targets.

After I add a folder reference to my project, there is no change to the files in Compile Sources -- as a result, building the project results in many `Undefined Symbols` problems. There are possibly a hundred `cpp` files in the subdirs of the folder I am adding, surely there is a way to add them to the project without individually adding each one to the Compile Sources? That would be error prone as well as time-consuming.

Comment: There is a halfway-house; multi-select source file from the file dialog.

Comment: @trojanfoe there is surely another way to add the entire folder and its sources, as the Apple doc suggests. It will take me hours to go through every subdir and add individual cpp files.

Comment: As I said, you will have to go to each sub-dir, but once there you can add multiple-files.  There is no other way.

Comment: @trojanfoe if that's true, that is ridiculous. There are several dozen subdirs, I will spend half the day doing that. I cannot imagine Xcode doesn't offer a better solution. Why does the Apple doc indicate otherwise?

Comment: It's like that with all IDEs isn't it?  Only recently I was adding existing source files to Visual Studio and that is similarly tedious.  As far as the Apple docs is concerned, I have no idea what that is even talking about.

Comment: @trojanfoe it turns out there IS a way to get ALL the files recursively into the Compile Sources by selecting just the parent folder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24701071/3758484  this worked for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When adding a folder of source files, or an arbitrary tree of folders that contain source files, you can have them all automatically get added to the Compile Sources by selecting one option when you add the files:

`Create groups for any added folders`

Without this, they will not be added. Big distinction, and it is *not* the default.

Comment: When you use this option then file system changes are not reflected, and you have to add every new file yourself to Compile Sources by clicking around in IDE settings.

Comment: Why was this info so hard to find? thank you so much